# HorizontalPicker as horizontal Numberpicker

Tags: android, apk, numberpicker

I need a horizontal Numberpicker. I found some a solution here:

https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker

But I dont know how to import it in my Project. 
I've tried to add:

```
compile 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.1'
```

then:

```
<com.wefika.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
        xmlns:picker="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.wefika.horizontalpicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        android:ellipsize="none | start | middle | end | marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
        picker:values="@array/values"
        picker:dividerSize="@dimen/itemPadding"
        picker:sideItems="@integer/sideItems" />
```

But it didn't work... 
I think import the apk is the easiest way to do but I dont know how to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `@array/values`,  `@dimen/itemPadding` and `@integer/sideItems`